# Loign Screen (LightDM) Background is black in Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, lightdm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How To Change Login Screen Background On 11.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/99760/how-to-change-login-screen-background-on-11-10)

Hi I have installed Ubuntu tweak in ubuntu 11.10. I changed the login screen (lightdm) background using it. But as I logged out to see the new login screen background but all I got a black background with dots over it. I am disappoint and found no solution of the problem elsewhere. I can login but the background is black.Please guys help me how to fix this!

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/99760/how-to-change-login-screen-background-on-11-10

Comment: @Ravi - no need to delete - just flag the question to mark as a duplicate.