# Change the login screen background and logo?

Tags: login

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change the wallpaper in LightDM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64001/how-do-i-change-the-wallpaper-in-lightdm)

How to change the login screen background as well as the logo that is placed down, without using any tool like simple lightdm manager?