# How do I change the purple dotted background in unity-greeter before the default background image?

Tags: 12.04, unity-greeter

How do I change the default purple dotted background that appears right before the background image in unity greeter in 12.04 precise?

To be clear, this is in the brief moment right before the unity-greeter user wallpaper is displayed in 12.04 (although this occured previous to 12.04 that's what I'm using).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is evidently a known bug.  https://bugs.launchpad.net/lightdm/+bug/970024 but there is a patch that can be applied.

Detailed instructions to install the patch for users not familiar with patching and recompiling are posted in this thread on ubuntu forums:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11846018#post11846018

Make sure to read the entire thread before following the steps, as the actual compilation is done differently than posted by the op (in order to make the modified unity-greeter a .deb package).

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/121381/54834) says it all.

[This thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11687752#post11687955) discussing the unity-greeter config file might help.

Earlier when I tried to change my desktop background, the image I'd had from 11.10 was obviously no longer an option. So I downloaded it to ~/Pictures and re-selected it as the background.  I think this fixed the greeter issue for me.

Comment: It should say it all, unfortunately it does not.  I'm speaking about right before the wallpaper appears, there is a brief second when I see the purple background with the grid, that is what I want to get rid of.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Imagine the linked site goes down for maintenance, or even forever: Your post would be useless to someone having the problem outlined here.