# How Do I configure LightDM to run seamlessly?

Tags: 12.04, lightdm, unity-greeter

My Unity Greeter/LightDM is working fine in Precise with one exception.

When the greeter first displays the default system wallpaper */usr/share/backgrounds/warty-final-ubuntu.png is* visible for 1 second, before dynamic LightDM kicks in.  Its more of a nuisense than anything, but **what options do I have to configure this to make it run seamlessly?**

I have looked at other related AU Q&A  and UF with no success and I have reviewed the configuration at

> gksu gedit /etc/lightdm/unity-greeter.conf

Comment: perhaps you can clarify - are you asking how to turn off "dynamic" lightdm wallpaper?

Comment: No, I really like this feature and the answer to turning it off already exists here. What I am trying to resolve is this.  My chosen desktop wallpaper appears dynamically (No issues here)  before it is displayed there is a split second when the default wallpaper is displayed.  This happens for all logins.  Its not a showstopper its just an inconvenience/a nusience and I thought someone out there may know how to fix it.  Every thing else works great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the wallpaper to match your "dynamic" backgoroud or, change it to - something like a black, or dark purple background so you don't notice the switch, [How do I change the wallpaper of the login screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64001/how-do-i-change-the-wallpaper-in-lightdm)  , otherwise you will notice when it changes from the default to your dynamic.

Maybe its a bug, who knows? If you turn off the dynamic wallpaper it will still show a transition from a purple background to a custom wallpaper.

**Note to benefit others:**
Answer accepted as it improved LightDM transition, however it did not fully resolve the issue.  Complete resolution would be nice, its a "paper over the cracks" solution (the black background).

Comment: Thanks, its a "paper over the cracks" solution (the black background) but one I may have to resort to if there is no fix. I wonder if I am the only one with this issue, if not maybe its a bug, who knows?