# How to restore lightdm guest's wallpaper?

Tags: 12.04, lightdm, desktop-background

Recently I played a bit on changing lightdm wallpaper... Actually LightDM shows the user wallpaper but not the default guest wallpaper (instead it shows a uniform purple background for guest account). How can I restore it?

Comment: You can try this instruction http://askubuntu.com/questions/64001/how-do-i-change-the-wallpaper-in-lightdm

Comment: This worked, However now the guest wallpaper is the same of my account.

Answer (score 1):

Try running this in the terminal, this will reinstall lightdm, but i am not sure if it resets the configurations:
**sudo apt-get --reinstall install lightdm**

Answer (score 0):

Better:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge lightdm
sudo apt-get install lightdm
```

Maybe you'll not be able to change the background for different users. If you want that, maybe you should log in with the user you want and then use simple-lightdm manager or ubuntu tweak like softwares.

Comment: did not work...