# Unity greeter background on Xubuntu 12.04

Tags: xubuntu, lightdm, desktop-background, unity-greeter

I'm running Xubuntu 12.04 and using the Unity greeter with LightDM. Everything works well except for I can never change the background. I've tried editing the .conf file, editing the gsettings as the lightdm user, even compiling an override file for `com.canonical.unity-greeter`. All of these fail, and I end with a dark purple background. I was able to get rid of the grid using gsettings, but that's about it. I've enabled switching user backgrounds, but that never works. I'm wondering whether this is Xfce/Xubuntu specific, or a bug.

Comment: Have you reviewed the answers to this question (similar to yours).  http://askubuntu.com/questions/64001/how-do-i-change-the-wallpaper-in-lightdm/121594#121594

Comment: I have tried that and still got a purple background. I think it might have something to do with the way xfce stores their backgrounds. They store them in /usr/share/xfce4/backgrounds, while Unity (and thus unity-greeter) store them in /usr/share/backgrounds. The Xubuntu team is working on a patched unity-greeter for 12.10, maybe that will fix some issues.

Answer (score 1):

Install dconf-editor from the Software Center and then "change" your background editing the  entry in dconf. That way it will read correctly your background (probably xfce and gnome store the "background" value in different ways, so this way you are telling lightdm where is the background in the "gnome" way.
I'm trying this right now

Comment: Tried usgin dconf and gconf, but it was no use. I like to test so opened a gnome session and changed again the wallpaper (my wallpaper was already set) and puf! it works now.

Answer (score -2):

First install `dconf-editor`
Then change your background picture.
at least . be happy ;)

Comment: Could you be more descriptive to your answer?