# Ubuntu-Tweak login background

Tags: login-screen, ubuntu-tweak

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change the wallpaper in LightDM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64001/how-do-i-change-the-wallpaper-in-lightdm)

I changed my login wallpaper to an image,which is different from my desktop background,using Ubuntu Tweak. When I logout/restart, it briefly displays the changed background, but fades to the old desktop background.

Comment: Can you be more explicit please ?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the answer you're looking for is **[here](https://askubuntu.com/a/64002/18612)**.

After you follow the steps, do the Ubuntu Tweak thing.

I believe Ubuntu Tweak is not working correctly because of the *Dynamic Background* that the *Unity Greeter* has. If you try this let us know the result. Have a good day.

Answer (score 0):

If I guess what you meant, it could be a problem about the owner of the file. It should be `root` instead of you.