# Personalized wallpaper picture should not show in lock screen

Tags: lock-screen, desktop-background

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I change the wallpaper in LightDM?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64001/how-do-i-change-the-wallpaper-in-lightdm)

I have been trying to find an answer to this, but it doesn't seem to be possible to find someone who has had a similar issue, although I find that hard to believe.
Nonetheless, here's the issue.

When I work on my computer, I like having a picture of my better half on the screen, so that every now and then, when I take a short break, I can look at her, smile, and go back to work. But when I lock the screen, that picture remains the background picture, and quite frankly, I wouldn't appreciate other people looking at her when I'm not on the PC.

Any pointers into the right direction would be greatly appreciated! It's 12.10 btw.

Comment: One solution may be to install a screen saver application and set it to activate as soon as the screen is locked.