# Ubuntu 12.04 login screen: go directly to user background, not via default

Tags: lightdm, login-screen, desktop-background, unity-greeter

I know I'm being rather picky here, but is there a way to configure lightdm so that when the login screen shows after boot it directly shows the selected user's background, instead of first loading the default screen and then fading to the user's background?

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 with Unity (3D) and lightdm.

Comment: You are saying that there are a few seconds where the user background is not displayed, right?

Comment: @Lucio: Yeah. When booting I see first the Ubuntu logo with a few dots under. When the dots are filled, the login screen is shown with the default background, which then fades to my personal background. I'd like to go directly from the logo with dots to my personal background =)

Comment: So yeah. I'm being *really* picky here, I know... But regardless of if it *is* possible, I think it *should be* - and there's no harm in asking, right? =)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change the wallpaper in LightDM?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/64001/how-do-i-change-the-wallpaper-in-lightdm/64002#64002). Take a look at the [accepted answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/64002/106635), seems to have solved the same issue the original asker had.

Comment: @oaskamay: That solves this temporarily; however, if I change my desktop background in the future, it won't propagate. Also, if possible I'd like to keep the feature that the background on the login window switches to the currently selected user's - but I want to get rid of the initial loading of the default.

Comment: Hmmm... In that case, I'm not sure what you want is possible or not.