# How can I use custom wallpapers for the login screen?

Tags: lightdm, login-screen, desktop-background

I recently Installed 12.10 version and I loved it! But the there's something weird with Wallpapers. As long as I use a wallpaper from the /usr/share/backgrounds folder (I use the "appearance" dialog box), this wallpapers appears also on my welcome (login) screen. But when I try to use a wallpaper from my pictures folder (again using the "+" button from the appearance dialog box), my login screen has the standard ubuntu 12.10 wallpaper. Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the `Pictures` folder the default one i.e. located at `/home/username/Pictures`?

Comment: Firstly, thanks for your reply! Secondly, yes! And i can also find the files through terminal. I tried "sudo cp /home/anthie/Pictures/Wallpapers/1.jpg /usr/share/backgrounds" but  even though the image was copied it was corrupted and it never showed up in the Appearance dialog box :/ Any ideas?

Comment: When you copy the picture to `/usr/share/backgrounds` you also need to change the permissions - read-write for owner and read-only for others. This can be accomplished by `sudo chmod 644 filename`. Also, is your home directory encrypted? Lastly, you need not thank everyone, this is just the way AskUbuntu works.

Comment: Ok! :) Good evening, first of all :) Secondly, I really used the "sudo chmod 644" command you suggested and now the .jpg file can be opened with the Image Viewer from the /usr/share/backgrounds folder, but it's still not visible to the "Appearance Dialog Box"

Comment: NEWS! :))))) Well, even though it's not accessible from the appearance dialog box it works!! :) I opened my "filesystem", navigated to the folder /usr/share/backgrounds and then I opened the .jpg using Image Viewer. Only a "right-click-set-as-desktop-background" was needed! :) Thank you for your help :) (and yes! I should thank you as much as each and everyone in here for providing their knowledge and experience. But most of all, thank you for the time you spent reading and replying to my question :) )

Comment: PS. Would you like to copy/paste your comments as an answer so that I can click the "tick" mark? :)

Comment: Yep. Your questions help others who face the same problem, so you really don't need to thank anyone or one thing can be that both thank each other which, ofcourse, doesn't seem much senseful. :)

Comment: I think this is a dupe:http://askubuntu.com/questions/64001/how-do-i-change-the-wallpaper-in-lightdm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you copy the picture to `/usr/share/backgrounds` you also need to change the permissions - read-write for owner and read-only for others.

This can be accomplished by running the following command in a terminal:

```
sudo chmod 644 filename
```

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu tweak can do this:

[image]

My login now shows dragonlady.

Comment: I really thank you for your reply! :) I started thinking of using Ubuntu Tweak! :) But now I'm also curious! I mean if there is the option of auto change (depending on my desktop wallpaper), why should I use the Tweak Tool? But yes. It's my only option, if I don't find out why it happens, your answer saves me :) Thank you :)

Comment: I tried to add in a pix of my login but several attempts failed horribly :X Don't forget to upvote and accept it if acceptable ;)

Comment: Good evening! I do have news for Ubuntu-Tweak. I clicked on "set as desktop background" but I get a purple background :/ Is there any solution?