# How do I fix corrupt background in LightDM?

Tags: nvidia, lubuntu, lightdm, mac-mini

After a fresh installation of Lubuntu 13.10 the default background image is distorted (the provided image shows a part of it). All GUI elements are displayed correctly. If I then select a different user in the drop-down list, like the Guest Session, the background is reloaded and displays correctly.

Does anyone know how to fix this problem? I use a MacMini 3,1 with an Nvidia GeForce 9400M graphics card and a 1280x1024 (LCD) monitor.

[image: part of Lubuntu background image]

Comment: Do '.png' files load normally? - could be graphics. Anyway, if the GUI's work, just [change the background](http://askubuntu.com/questions/64001/how-do-i-change-the-wallpaper-in-lightdm) *(perhaps to a `jpg`, as I think the default background is `png`)*. This also allows for any customization if you want any.

Comment: PNG files load normally in the sense that the default background is displayed correctly after I switch user in LightDM (without logging in). I suspect that the display corruption is caused by the display driver for some reason not getting the correct screen resolution initially.

Comment: Changing the background still might help - it is simple as [changing one line in the config file](http://askubuntu.com/a/64003/178596). If you want to ask about Nvidia drivers, search the forum first, as half the questions on here seem to be about Nvidia drivers.

Comment: @wilf OK, thanks for the input. I'll change the background while waiting for a real fix.