# Grey screen background during logon

Tags: 13.10, lubuntu, login, login-screen, remote-login

Earlier during log on my screen's background used to be purple,but now it has become grey in colour,is it OK?But can anyone tell me why does did it happen.And,how can I switch from Lubuntu to Ubuntu?Which is better Lubuntu or Ubuntu?And how can I use the Remote login feature of Ubuntu 13.10?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Don't worry saisanjeev, if you can still login there isn't any problem: read [this askUbuntu article](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64001/how-do-i-change-the-wallpaper-in-lightdm/64002#64002) to know why you background is now dynamic and not static.
- For the other questions: Lubuntu is made for low end machines (like Asus EeePc) and uses less memory and less CPU than Ubuntu, but uses [lxde Desktop Enviroment](http://lxde.org/) as Graphical User Interface and has different software & updates than Ubuntu. Pass to Lubuntu **if** you notice lag in your current Ubuntu installation, I also *suggest* to try Lubuntu in Live before using it.
- Last, for the Remote Desktop feature follow [this unofficial guide](http://www.howtoforge.com/configure-remote-access-to-your-ubuntu-desktop).

Please, if you have more questions comment under here and don't forget to press the UP arrow. :-)
Have a nice experience and **Don't Panic**, Linux is made for tweaking.

Comment: What is dynamic and Static?

Comment: How to install ubuntu in lubuntu?

Comment: A dynamic log-on background will change to reflect the selected user's desktop background colour, unlike a static one. Other question: you can't install Ubuntu IN lubuntu (you can still virtualize it, but is useless), you can install lubuntu in another partition on the HD (it will appear as a new GRUB boot loader entry) or replace ubuntu or any other Operative System; in any case backup your personal data. Lubuntu can be installed like Ubuntu, follow this Lubuntu Community's Official Guide: " https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Lubuntu/InstallingLubuntu "
Good day, ask if needed.

Comment: I actually had ubuntu 13.10.When I was trying to configure the LXDE and other desktop environments,it changed to Lubuntu,how can I revert it?Is there any system restore like in Windows?

Comment: You only changed graphic enviroment, not distribution; you can't change distribution from Ubuntu itself (ex. Ubuntu --> Lubuntu, or Lubuntu --> Ubuntu), you need the new distribution DVD. There is no preinstalled system restore. SOLUTION (if you don't like LXDE): connect to internet and use your packet manager to install gNome and then remove LXDE, the system will (hopefully) configure all for you; alternatively use your personal Ubuntu DVD to restore or reinstall your system. Always have a backup of your personal data before doing anything. Good working. :)

Comment: How can I remove LXDE and how can I install Unity?

Comment: or gnome?Which is better Unity or gnome

Comment: I can't tell you here which is "better", this is *very* subjective and you should both try Unity and gnome personally on your machine. If you want, contact me in private to ask my opinion on anything, I'll be happy to talk. :) To remove and install any software package follow the official guide: https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/package-management.html 
If you have difficulties you can, I only suggest, use Synaptics: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticHowto