# Setting custom font issues

Tags: android, fonts, customization

Currently, I'm working on setting FreeSans as the standard font in my Ubuntu installation. But it stays ubuntu at three places: The category headers in the Unity dash, the text at the logout, shutdown etc. views and the user name, password etc. (everything except window title) in the login manager.

What have I forgot?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

1. Change directory:

   ```
   cd /etc/lightdm
   ```
2. Make backup for the current configuration:

   ```
   sudo cp unity-greeter.conf unity-greeter.conf.bak
   ```
3. Edit `unity-greeter` configuration file:

   ```
   gksu gedit /etc/lightdm/unity-greeter.conf
   ```

   OR

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/lightdm/unity-greeter.conf
   ```
4. You will see presumably there:

   ```
   #
   # background = Background file to use, either an image path or a color (e.g. #772953)
   # logo = Logo file to use
   # theme-name = GTK+ theme to use
   # font-name = Font to use
   # xft-antialias = Whether to antialias Xft fonts (true or false)
   # xft-dpi = Resolution for Xft in dots per inch (e.g. 96)
   # xft-hintstyle = What degree of hinting to use (hintnone, hintslight, hintmedium, or hintfull)
   # xft-rgba = Type of subpixel antialiasing (none, rgb, bgr, vrgb or vbgr)
   #
   [greeter]
   background=/usr/share/backgrounds/warty-final-ubuntu.png
   logo=/usr/share/unity-greeter/logo.png
   theme-name=Ambiance
   icon-theme-name=ubuntu-mono-dark
   font-name=Ubuntu 11
   xft-antialias=true
   xft-dpi=96
   xft-hintstyle=hintslight
   xft-rgba=rgb
   ```

Once I saw some bug at Launchpad, near about "Unity Greeter font do not changes", however common practice people use it widely. Change the property `font-name=Ubuntu 11` look alike:

```
font-name=FreeSans 11
```

Save your configuration file.

```
#try restart LightDM
sudo service lightdm restart
```

And log out, or just restart all (sometimes it is needed):

```
sudo reboot
```

**Enjoy.**

[look this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64001/how-do-i-change-the-wallpaper-of-the-login-screen)
equal result with `dconf` editor:

[image: dconf Unity Greeter]

Comment: Already using Unity Tweak Tool. It doesn't set the FreeSans font where I would like it to be (the 3 places mentioned in the start post)

Comment: will be the best if you add screen to your question, that save our time

Comment: globally updated