# Login Screen background changes itself before login in (ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: login-screen, desktop-background

I changed the default login screen wallpaper to a custom one as well as the desktop background to a another custom one(basically I have two different backgrounds one for login screen and one for desktop).

Unfortunately recently it started to act weird. At the startup the login screen wallpaper shows for like half a second and then it automatically changes to the desktop wallpaper before I even log in. I don't use anything else to change the backgrounds apart from unity tweak tool and to change the login screen I replaced the default file in /usr/share/backgrounds.

It's a minor problem but I cannot solve it myself and need some help.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Ubuntu 12.04 Unity greeter has introduced selected user dynamic background, that means that when selecting a user from the available users list the background will change to reflect the selected user's desktop background."

Please follow this guide: [How do I change the wallpaper of the login screen?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64001/how-do-i-change-the-wallpaper-of-the-login-screen)

(Follow the steps under "Setting the dynamic switching off")

Comment: As this question is not (according to the question itself) a duplicate of the question linked to above, I didn't mark it as such, but in theory one could.

Comment: Oh wow. I feel silly right now because I read that guide and didn't think it would work in my case. In any case, thanks!